# BackTrack Linux question - which site?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a question regarding [BackTrack Linux](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/) ISO customization. Apparently the stock ISO is missing some drivers and uses an older kernel. My question is: (other than the BackTrack forum) should I ask my question on StackOverflow or ServerFault? I would hate to see it bounced around :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- This is not about programming, so [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) isn't a good fit.
- This is not about administering multiple computers, so [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) isn't a good fit.
- This is about administering your own computer, so [Super User](https://superuser.com/) is a good fit.
- Backtrack is not Ubuntu (it's a derivative, but that doesn't count), hence [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) is out.
- This is about Unix, so [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) is a good fit.

Personally, I'd ask on Unix. Failing that I'd try SU as a last resort.

Comment: @badp why do you say that Super User would be a last resort?

Answer (score 2):

Neither - in my opinion, https://unix.stackexchange.com/ would be the right place to ask. The question isn't about programming, or servers; but it will definitely fit into a site about Linux and other UN*Xes.